# is there any option to get highchart plotbands only for one xaxis?

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I am using highchart to get bar chart, i have used plotbands here so my requirement is i need to get the plotband only for the one row xaxis.
here it is the snippet for example.
https://jsfiddle.net/z6kug43w/20/

```
xAxis: {
    plotBands: [{
        from: 0.4,
      to: 0.6,
      color: '#fff',                     
      zIndex: 3
    },
    {
        from: 1.4,
      to: 1.6,
      color: '#fff',                     
      zIndex: 3
    },
    {
        from: 2.4,
      to: 2.6,
      color: '#fff',                     
      zIndex: 3
    },
    {
        from: 3.4,
      to: 3.6,
      color: '#fff',                     
      zIndex: 3
    }],
    categories: ["abc (1%)", "abcd (1%)", "abce (1%)", "abcf (1%)", "abcg (1%)", "abch (1%)"],
    crosshair: true
},
```

yAxis: {
min: 0,
plotBands: [{
from: 0,
to: 100,
thickness: '2%',
color: '#D5D5D6'
}],
title: {
text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
}
},

Comment: can you share any image that you want to plot ?

Comment: Hi @FakerMakesActualCorrect, Thanks for helping me here,
i have shared that image in description.
that i want to plot only top level of the graph.

Comment: What's the difference both image are same ?

Comment: like in the image i want the plot band for top level for now it is getting for all the xaxis rows as in the example https://jsfiddle.net/z6kug43w/20/.
Just uploaded once again for you i thought image is not visible, please ignore the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at this custom plugin which allows you to defining the `low` and `high` values for the plotBands.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/n3okxjug/

```
  xAxis: {
    categories: ["abc (1%)", "abcd (1%)", "abce (1%)", "abcf (1%)", "abcg (1%)", "abch (1%)"],
    crosshair: true,
    plotBands: [{
      from: 0.5,
      to: 1.5,
      color: 'red',
      low: '60%',
      high: '100%'
    }]
  },
```

Is this a result which you wanted to achieve?

Comment: Hi @sebastian wedzel, Yes exactly i need this type but how can i achieve this dynamically

Comment: what do you have in mind? Could you share more details?

Comment: hi @sebastian wedzel, its working Thanks for helping